# Possible ways to find sponsor for world tour / adventure type trip around world

Tags: international-travel, tips-and-tricks, adventure, around-the-world

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but...

I was wondering what are possible ways to find sponsors for one's world tour or adventurous trip, I have seen sometimes people do want someone to go on adventures with them or rich people who just want others to come along for fun.

I Love traveling but unfortunately just lived in two different countries but I want to go on a world tour or live in different countries. If i make any sense :).

Comment: FYI, this is not a forum.. this is a Q&A site.

Comment: sorry, I meant forum as "place" not like online forums :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finding sponsors is mostly about social skills.

Traveling to help some sort of aid project, raise awareness or some other excuses seems to help in finding sponsors.

The actual trip is of little importance, just make it sound like an achievement.

For example, I know a couple who cycled all the way from [Amsterdam, to the North cape, and then down to Cape of good hope](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Amsterdam,+The+Netherlands&daddr=E69+to%3aCape+of+Good+Hope,+Cape+of+Good+Hope,+Cape+Town,+South+Africa&hl=en&ll=31.503629,42.539063&spn=108.476365,270.527344&sll=18.479609,15.292969&sspn=114.158684,270.527344&geocode=FSgbHwMdwLFKAClVd5qUtT_GRzGNr8C3TP0AZg%3BFdjvPQQdiGWJAQ%3BFejA8_0dxOIZASE34wF-ooHcLCmN2uPH_yLMHTE34wF-ooHcLA&oq=cape+of+good+hope,+so&t=h&mra=iwd&z=3). They did *not* have any sponsors.

In contrast, I recently read about a couple, with several sponsors, who planned on cycling all the way from [Amsterdam to Barcelona](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Amsterdam,+The+Netherlands&daddr=Barcelona,+Spain&hl=en&ll=46.875213,3.186035&spn=12.37988,33.815918&sll=46.888192,3.562711&sspn=12.376441,33.815918&geocode=FSgbHwMdwLFKAClVd5qUtT_GRzGNr8C3TP0AZg%3BFY2HdwIdPxwhACn1KO0mcZikEjEwA6Qh4PoABA&t=h&mra=ls&z=6). They and their sponsors presented it as an unprecedented adventure. They had lots of sponsored equipment, bikes and media attention.

*Sponsorship also will limit your freedom*

Keep in mind that making a sponsored trip is not just about receiving funding: the sponsor generally expects you to do something in return. This can be as simple as promoting their product, but could extend all the way to being present at some predetermined place at a certain date and time, give interviews or anything they choose to put in the sponsor contract.

Comment: Unprecedented? I can name 5 people off the top of my head who have done that trip by bike.  Genius marketing :)

Comment: yeah, it brought a bit of a smile to my face as well.

Answer (score 0):

A couple friends I know used the following way

- They got their accomodation close to free just by staying with friends, acquaintainces or offering to hosts guests in their own country in return for free stay (do not think they stayed anywhere for more than a week)
- They used public transport for intra country travel
- Only thing they paid for was their airline tickets from 1 country to another
- They worked for a couple of years, planning for this trip and saving money for it.

Remember world tour is a very ambiguous word. You can begin with making a list of countries you want to travel to and how long you plan to be there. Also you can check out

- Airbnb.com
- Youth Hostels

These can provide economical options as well